# How do I unit test connection failures on a DataSource with Postgresql backend?

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, database-connection

To test the behaviour of a web service during database outages I would like to simulate connection failures in my unit tests. The database backend is Postgresql and the code uses some non-standard SQL queries that make it hard to use a vanilla in-memory database for testing. The database connection is accessible through a [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) that defers connection management to a ConnectionPool.

How can I simulate temporary/intermitent database disconnects in a unit test to verify correct error handling and recovery from connection outages?

Comment: Create a mock connection that fails.

Comment: I need a connection that works initially, then fails after a few seconds, then works again.

Comment: A mock is your only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @duffymo a mock is the way to go.

If you would really do *unit testing* you already would use Mocks created by a mocking framework since *unit tests* require isolation of the individual Units by replacing their *dependencies* with *test doubles*. A mocking framework is the simplest and most stable way to create such *test doubles*.

But I guess that you are instead doing *Integration Tests* executed with a *UnitTesting Framework*, calling them "unit tests" for whatever reason.

However..

Since your test relies on the real functionality of the datasouces a *spy* would be a good choice like this:

```
class DatasourceUsageTest{    
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
    @Test
    public void reportDatabaseOutage(){
        // arrange
        DataSource myDatasource = aquireDatasourceSomehow();
        DataSource spyOfMyDatasource = Mockito.spy(myDatasource);

        Mockito.doCallRealMethod() // first call
          .doThrow(new SqlException("Report this message") // second call (and all following) 
          .when(spyOfMyDatasource).methodExpectedToFail();

        SomeType testedUnit = createUnitAndInject(spyOfMyDatasource );

       // act call #1
       testedUnit.theMethodUsingDatasource(); 
       Mockito.verify(spyOfMyDatasource).methodExpectedToFail();

       // act call #2
       exception.expect(TheExceptionTypeToBeThrown.class);
       exception.expectMessage(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_PREFIX + "Report this message"); 
       testedUnit.theMethodUsingDatasource(); 
      // Code below this will not be executed
    }
}
```

Problem here (as with any *Integration test*) is that your database may have a real Problem in which case this test fails at call #1 (and thus for the wrong reason).

Comment: You guessed right and I was using the wrong terminology.